# Why am I getting "type object 'About' has no attribute 'objects'"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am new to Django and I am making a search bar and which I added the logic in views.py, it threw this error "type object 'About' has no attribute 'objects'" I can't figure out why

```
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, ListView, DetailView
from .models import About


#views

class Home(ListView):
    """docstring for Home"""
    template_name = 'home.html'
    model = About
    recents = About.objects.all()
    context_object_name = 'recents'



class BiographyDetail(DetailView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""
    model = About
    template_name = 'details.html'


class About(TemplateView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""

    template_name = 'about.html'
    model = About


class Contacts(TemplateView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""

    template_name = 'contact.html'
    model = About


class Projects(TemplateView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""

    template_name = 'projects.html'
    model = About


class Search(ListView):
    """docstring for BiographyDetail"""

    template_name = 'search.html'
    model = About
    def get_queryset(self): # new
        query = self.request.GET.get('search')
        searches = About.objects.filter(
            Q(name__icontains=query)
            )
        return searches
```

This is my models.py folder

```
#models.py
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
import datetime
# Create your models here.

TYPE = (
    ('politician','POLITICIAN'),
    ('poet','POET'),
    ('author','AUTHOR'),
    ('actor','ACTOR'),
    )




class About(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default ='')
    quote = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default ='')
    born = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Born on', null = True)
    born_at = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default ='')
    died = models.DateField(verbose_name = 'Born on', null = True)
    died_at = models.CharField(max_length = 200, default ='')
    main = models.TextField(default='')
    category = models.CharField(choices = TYPE, default = 'poet', max_length = 10)
    image = models.ImageField(blank = True, default='',upload_to = 'static')
    created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add = True)
    updated_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.created_on >=timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=15)
```

What am I doing wrong, please help me

Comment: What do you expect `About.objects` to do?  There isn't any class variable with that name.

Comment: You named the view `About` as well, hence it will take that one.

Comment: Please use a `View` suffix in your views.

Comment: It also looks rather *odd* to have a model per view. Models are not supposed to be used for a view. Models are supposed to make certain data *persistent*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a conflict between your `class About(models.Model):` and your `class About(TemplateView):`

You did not paste the imports in your files but I'm pretty sure the `About` in your `Home` and your `Search` classes is using your `About` view and not your `About` model.

I would suggest you rename some things (`About` -> `AboutView` for example) so you don't have these exact same class names. That should make things more obvious so you can figure out what's going on.